# If-else statement not working properly

Tags: java, jsp, if-statement

My website is just like SO. In this page I am trying to retrieve answered and unanswered questions in two separate tables. But in output I am getting both answered and unanswered questions being displayed in Answered Questions table. What is going wrong here ? I appreciate all help and effort. Here is my code :-

```
<%@page import="model.QuestionBean"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="model.QuestionDAO"%>
<%@page import="model.QuestionDAOFactory"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>All Questions</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>



                    <%
                    QuestionDAOFactory qdf=new QuestionDAOFactory();
                    QuestionDAO qd=qdf.createQuestionDAO();
                    List<QuestionBean> list=qd.getQuestions();
                    for (QuestionBean qb : list) {
                    %>

                        <%
                        if(qb.getIsAnswered().equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
                        %>
                        <table style="width: 50%;height: 100%;border: 1px solid black;" align="">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Answered Questions</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <%
                                    {
                                %>
                            <tr><td><a href="viewQuestion.jsp?id=<%=qb.getQuestionId() %>"><%=qb.getQuestionText() %></a></td></tr>
                                <%
                                    }
                                %>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>    
                        <%
                            else
                        %>
                        <table style="width: 50%;height: 100%;border: 1px solid black;" align="">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Unanswered Questions</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <%
                                    {
                                %>
                            <tr><td><a href="viewQuestion.jsp?id=<%=qb.getQuestionId() %>"><%=qb.getQuestionText() %></a></td></tr>
                                <%
                                    }
                                %>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>


                    <%
                        }
                    %>

            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The blocks of your if-else statement don't look right.

Try :

```
                    <%
                    if(qb.getIsAnswered().equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
                    %>
                      <table>
                        ...
                      </table>
                    <%
                    } else {
                    %> 
                      <table>
                        ...
                      </table>
                    <%
                    }
                    %>
```

EDIT:

After reading the question more carefully, it seems that the logic in your JSP is wrong. If you wish to display answered an un-answered questions in separate tables, you must first iterate over all the answered questions and put them in one table, and then iterate over all the unanswered questions and put them in the second table. You can achieve that, for example, with two loops :

```
<table ...>
...
<%
  for (QuestionBean qb : list) {
    if(qb.getIsAnswered().equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
%>
    ... show answered question ...
<%
    }
  }
%>
</table>
<table ...>
...
<%
  for (QuestionBean qb : list) {
    if(!qb.getIsAnswered().equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
%>
    ... show unanswered question ...
<%
    }
  }
%>
</table>
```

Or you can avoid the if statements by introducing `getAnsweredQuestions()` and `getUnAnsweredQuestions()` in your `QuestionDAO` class.

Your current logic appears to create a separate table for each question.

Comment: @CodeHungry are you referring to my answer before my edit or after the edit?

Comment: @CodeHungry Can you be more specific? What output do you see now?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in your if-else statement. Your getter telling me that the return value is a boolean but you make a string compare:

```
qb.getIsAnswered().equalsIgnoreCase("Y")
```

Change your data model or debug for the return value on this line.

Post your model class please.

Comment: If `qb.getIsAnswered()` returned a boolean, the code won't pass compilation (you can't call `equalsIgnoreCase` (or any method) for a `boolean`). Based on the problem description, this code produces an output (that is, unless the OP is seeing the output of a previous compilation of the JSP page).

Comment: If the getter is return a boolean there is no equals call required and the code is more readable. But the code above doing anything with check of "Y". I would suggest to change the value to boolean and to remove the equalsIgnoreCase

Answer (score 0):

Check the content of 'qb.getIsAnswered()'. It may be 'Y' always

Answer (score 0):

There's some problems:

- you're creating a new table for each QuestionBean, since the table definitions are within the for loop.
- you have an unmatched  tag at the end.

If you want 2 tables, and you stick to the API above you'll need two for loops to iterate through the returned list. One loop will render the Answered questions, the other the unanswered questions.

Something like this:

```
<%@page import="model.QuestionBean"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="model.QuestionDAO"%>
<%@page import="model.QuestionDAOFactory"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title>All Questions</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
        <%
          QuestionDAOFactory qdf=new QuestionDAOFactory();
          QuestionDAO qd=qdf.createQuestionDAO();
          List<QuestionBean> list=qd.getQuestions();
        %>
        <table style="width: 50%;height: 100%;border: 1px solid black;" align="">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Answered Questions</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <%
              for (QuestionBean qb : list) {
                if(qb.getIsAnswered().equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
            %>
            <tr><td><a href="viewQuestion.jsp?id=<%=qb.getQuestionId() %>"><%=qb.getQuestionText() %></a></td></tr>
             <%
                }
              }
             %>
          </tbody>
        </table>    
        <table style="width: 50%;height: 100%;border: 1px solid black;" align="">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Unanswered Questions</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
             <%
               for (QuestionBean qb : list) {
                 if(!qb.getIsAnswered().equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
             %>
             <tr><td><a href="viewQuestion.jsp?id=<%=qb.getQuestionId() %>"><%=qb.getQuestionText() %></a></td></tr>
             <%
                 }
               }
             %>
          </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I copy pasted your code. But its showing all answers in Unanswered Category.

Comment: That can only mean the getIsAnswered method always returns something different than 'Y' or 'y'. I'd advise to print the value or debug to check what value is used.